# Parsing oddly formatted permissions

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

I'm making a short, simple bash parser and trying to extract 3 things from many lines, and put them into newly formated variables. they are all formatted like below:

```
ownername:read write execute groupname:read execute all:none  sticky
```

I'm trying to pull each part into variables like below:

Owner (first block)

`OWNER=$(ownername)`

Group (second block)

`GROUP=$(groupname)`

and finally permissions (all blocks, but with ownername/groupname replaced with owner and primary_group)

`PERMISSIONS=$(owner:read write execute primary_group:read execute all:none  sticky)`

This seemed like a pretty simple task at first, however, trying to tackle this with my basic awk knowledge is difficult as some areas may be rwx, and others rw/ro, as well as the owner/group not being unique (not allowing a simple sed)

What are some first steps I can take approaching this?

To put it more clearly:

Input:

```
ownername:read write execute groupname:read execute all:none  sticky
```

Output:

```
OWNER=ownername
GROUP=groupname
PERMISSIONS=owner:read write execute primary_group:read execute all:none  sticky
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to split the input to the parts that have a single word, a colon, then some other words. It would be easier if the sections were separated, but you could e.g. add separators with something like this:

```
echo "ownername:read write execute groupname:read execute all:none  sticky" | \
   sed -e 's/\w\w*:/;&/g'
;ownername:read write execute ;groupname:read execute ;all:none  sticky
```

Splitting on the semicolons should be doable from that.

Obligatory Perl snippet, splitting the parts directly to an array:

```
echo "ownername:read write execute groupname:read execute all:none  sticky" | \
  perl -ne '@a = split/ (?=\w+:)/; print "$_\n" for @a'
ownername:read write execute
groupname:read execute
all:none  sticky
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, from here should be easy to expand, thanks!